# QPalette has no attribute PlaceholderText?

Tags: c++, qt, qpalette

I'm trying to build a Qt, but I get this error:

```
 C2039: "type object 'QPalette' has no attribute 'PlaceholderText'"
```

I tried to find where I'm using `PlaceholderText`, but couldn't.

Comment: There are enum values for the palette entries. Assume you have out-of-bound access somewhere and this stores a (not-so-)arbitrary number somewhere which is related to palette access...

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Color role `QPalette::PlaceholderText` exists since Qt 5.12. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum

[image]